# Show that no interval in R is a union of two disjoint nonempty open sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

What I did was to assume an interval **I** = (a,b) where a,b $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. We claim that **I** cannot be written as union of two disjoint non-empty open set.

Suppose there exists A,B subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that **I** = A$\cup$B. Hence, $\forall x \in$ **I** , $x \in A \cup B$. Say p = sup(A) and q = inf(B). Then either p < q, p > q or p = q (Trichotomy law).

But if p < q , $\exists x \in$ **I** such that p < x < q. Hence, $x \notin A \cup B $.

If p > q, $\exists x \in B$ such that x also belongs to A, which is contradiction to the hypothesis condition.

And if p = q, sup(A) = inf(B). But A and B are open sets. Hence p and q does not belong to set A and B respectively. Thus p = q is not in $A \cup B$ hence $I \neq A \cup B$.

Is this proof valid. Though I see that I need to prove that sup(A) and inf(B) must lie in **I** in first place. Also I am not allowed to use idea of connectedness. Please notice me other mistakes I missed and any gaps in the proof.

Comment: How do you know that if $p>q$ then $A$ and $B$ have an element in common? Note that $A,B$ need not be intervals themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That approach runs into the problem noted in the comments by Teresa Lisbon: $p>q$ does not immediately guarantee that some point of $(q,p)$ is in both $A$ and $B$. In fact, proving that amounts to proving the theorem for the interval $(q,p)$. I’ll suggest an approach that uses a lot of the same basic ideas but avoids that problem.

Start as you did, by assuming $(a,b)=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are non-empty open sets. Without loss of generality there are points $a_0\in A$ and $b_0\in B$ such that $a_0<b_0$. Let $A_0=\{x\in (a,b):[a_0,x)\subseteq A\}$, and let $p=\sup A_0$. You know that $p\in(a,b)$, because $a_0\le p\le b_0$. Thus, either $p\in A$, or $p\in B$. Show that neither of these is actually possible.